# How to implement session recording similar to Hotjar, but for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mutation-observers, hotjar, session-replay

For web apps you would simply use MutationObserver to log all DOM changes and then replay them. What are the options for mobile apps?

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest would be to use some 3rd party tool which is already doing some screen recording & replay.
For example [Appsee](https://www.appsee.com/app-analytics) or [smartlook](https://smartlook.github.io/docs/sdk/android/).

Of course you can try to develop your own solution but is quite a long path.

Also pay attention to user consent. There was some issue on Apple store with app removed because they were recording screen. I recommend to use [this sdk](https://www.producthunt.com/posts/smartlookconsentsdk) to manage user consent.